# JSON object: Get all objects to capitalize their first letters

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object that looks something like this (result from an AJAX call):

```
    json{
      code: 0,
      resultVal: Object {
      data: 
               [
                 Object{
                        generatedName: name1,
                        generatedValue: value1
                 },
                 Object{
                        generatedName1: name2,
                        generatedValue1: value2
                 }....
                ],
        anotherItem: true,
        ...
       }
     }
```

**To clarify** `resultVal` is an object and `data` is an array of objects, and each object in that array will have two values who's names I will not know in advance.

I am having a problem because I need `generatedName` and `generatedValue` to be `GenerateName` and `GeneratedValue`. These names and values are usually not the as each other. I know can access each Object through `json.resultVal.data[#]`, but that's as far as I have gotten. `json.resultVal.data[0].name` returns `undefined`.

Once I can get those values isolated I can make the fixes I need.

**NOTE** I am running these calls through Chrome's debugger. The thinking is once I am able to isolate the value I can write the code to fix it using that call. It takes some time to get to this point in the application.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you run your data through JSON Lint to see if it is valid?

Comment: You could certianly iterate over the objects and create new "copies" of these object by manually making first latte of properties uppercase then setting them on the copy, but this seems like it might be unnecessary effort if you reevaluate your need for this capitalization.  Why is this need?  Can it be changed in the server response if needed? Can it be changed in the code that consumes this data?  It just seems silly to add this logic for a simple case of property capitalization if it can just be avoided.

Comment: I haven't recently ran through the JSON to make sure it is valid. We made a change in our C# code to camel case all our JSON values that we return (for more of a standards thing). This code will call a JQuery table, which is expecting the first letter to be uppercase. Unfortunately we need to go through and capitalize the first word or each generatedName and generatedValue because of this.

Comment: I am assuming it is valid now, because it was valid before our camel casing change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood it right, you need to iterate over all keys for all objects in "json.resultVal.data". Try using a for/in loop to iterate over the "data" object, as in:

```
for( var i in json.resultVal.data ) {
    for( var k in json.resultVal.data[i] ) {
        /* here "k" will be key string ("generatedName", "generatedValue", ...) */
    }
}
```

Comment: Wanted to avoid a double for like this, but after doing some research, I haven't found a better way. Thanks!